# discord.py - message.content returns null

Tags: discord.py

I am currently trying to program my own Discord Bot with Python. I have now made an "on_message" event, but "message.content" is not returning anything. No message, nothing! Can you help me?

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith("$test"):
        await message.channel.send("test")
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have the `message_content` intent, so you can't read messages.

Docs: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html

Don't forget to enable them on your dev portal as well.

Also, instead of manually parsing messages with prefixes, consider using the built-in `Commands` framework that does all this for you. Docs: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html

PS "null" is not a thing in Python, it's `None`. And the message content isn't None/*"null"*, it's an empty string (`""`).